# How can I create a new servlet at a specific path?

Tags: tomcat

As of right now, I'm defining the servlet path with an annotation "@WebServlet("/mypath")" at the top of my class. Could I possibly make new instances of that class from another servlet so that the servlet is at "/otherservlet/newservlet"? How would I create an instance of the servlet class while specifying the path?

I'm using Tomcat and the HttpServlet class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/mypath", "/otherservlet/newservlet"})
```

See also:

- [Configuring Web Applications: The hello2 Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html)
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this in runtime? For example, if two clients want to create a chatroom at "pathtohoster/chatroomID", how would the program create the message servlet at that path?

Comment: Have you seen the WebSockets?

Comment: They seem interesting, but I've already written the code for my servlet. So is there any way to create a servlet at a given url?